# Bootstrap4 - вывод сетки блоков обходя определенный блок в центре

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

нужна помощь.
Как сверстать систему сеток, так что бы добавленные блоки обходили определенный блок находящийся именно по центру

на пример

|_ col *|* col *|* col *|* Staick block *|* col *|* col *|* col _|

Вот Staick block всегда находится по центру, даже если удалить один блок слева или справа Staick block всегда остается в центре

Может, кто поможет выполнить данный момент
Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]